# Multiple Choice Selections involving Vectors

Tags: stdvector

Does anyone know how it is possible to create a multiple choice when dealing with elements in vectors? The purpose of my code is to output a series of vector elements and then the User choose a card which is defined by class card. This is my code so far:

```
while(true){
    cout << players[0] << endl;
    cout << "What to Do: ";
    string input; cin >> input;
    if (input == "?") {
        for(int i = 1, len = players.size(); i < len; ++i) cout << players[i] << endl;
    }
    if (input == "quit") break;

    card hold;
    switch(input){
    case "a" : hold = players.back(); players[6] = players[0]; players[0] = hold;
    case "b" : hold = players.back(); players[6] = players[1]; players[1] = hold;
    case "c" : hold = players.back(); players[6] = players[2]; players[2] = hold;
    case "d" : hold = players.back(); players[6] = players[3]; players[3] = hold;
    case "e" : hold = players.back(); players[6] = players[4]; players[4] = hold;
    case "f" : hold = players.back(); players[6] = players[5]; players[5] = hold;
    case "g" : hold = players.back(); players[6] = hold;
    }
```